# how to time out a session and perform an action before timing out by acessing the session info?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, session-variables, shopping-cart

I am storing the items of shopping cart into a session array, but since the product ids and quantity is being stored on the client side , I can't perform a check on the quantity of items when a customer wants to add an item whose available quantity is already added to other customers carts.

So I have added a column called `added_to_cart` in my `Products` table  which increments when a product/item is added to a customers session cart.

Now I want to time out the session when there's no activity by the customer for an hour and decrement the `added_to_cart` by checking what's stored in the inactive(to be timed out)php session

```
    Products
    -----------------------------------------
    : p_id  : available_qty : added_to_cart :
    -----------------------------------------
    : p-123 :  57           : 3             :
    -----------------------------------------
    : p-287 :  32           : 8             :
    -----------------------------------------
```

1.Is it possible to do it when the customer doesn't visit the site ever after(i.e without calling the session_start()).If so how?.

2.Is it the right proposed solution?How do they do it in bigger online stored like amazon and ebay?

Comment: 1: yes it's possible. 2: no it's not. the quantity decreases when someone BUY something. If you are in supermarket and take some products to basket. The product leaves from the market when you pay them NOT when you add them to your basket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the FINAL quantity check when order is placed/submitted, not when added to cart. Think what happens, if somebody adds all products in your system to cart (just for fun).. your eCommerce shop would be sold out :)

So should be like:

- when viewing item available quantity (in stock quantity) use value from database (real, current, available quantity)
- when order is submitted, check that the quantity ordered is available. If not, notify user. If is, make the reduction and save to DB.

There is also lot of well maid, free eCommerce softwares available like: Magento (http://magento.com/)

TIMED SESSIONS:

But if you really want to do the session thing, you can:

- save sessions to database with timestamp
- update timestamp on every page request by user (like "last access")
- periodically delete old session rows and "free" reserved products

Keep in mind that the sessions (reserved products related) should then be quite short (like 30 minutes?).

Comment: Imagine what a tragic experience will it be when you add some products to your cart and when you are about to checkout , the website says that the products you added to your cart are no more available.The customer will feel he has wasted his time on your site.and what I was trying to say was that the product is not sold out when you've added to the cart but unavailable for the period when someone has it in his cart.You don't pick products from others carts while shopping Do you?

Comment: eCommerce and "real world" shops are two different things. As i said your shop would be sold out if someone is just playing a round. All web-shops in the world are working as i explained. If you want to do it non-proper way, feel free to do that..